# ngModel solution for Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I need populate the selected option from a select angular material element to a textarea. I am using ngModel and it worked but I got the error as follow in console:

```
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
in Angular v7.

For more information on this, see our API docs here:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel
```

For angular 8 ngModel is deprecated so could anybody give me a solution please?

My code is as follow:

**myComponent.component.html**

```
<form class="reminder-message" [formGroup]="reminderMessageForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="reminderMessage(f.value)">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width select">
        <mat-select formControlName="option" placeholder="Choose a reminder" [(ngModel)]="selectedReminder" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of optionMessages" [value]="opt.message">{{ opt.option }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="full-width textarea-message">
        <textarea matInput formControlName="reminder" value="{{ selectedReminder }}" cols="5" rows="7" readonly></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-dialog-actions class="actions" align="end">
        <button mat-button class="send-message action" [disabled]="!buttonDisabled" type="submit">
            <span>Send</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="close action" (click)="closeDialog()">
            <span>Close</span>
        </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

**myComponent.component.ts**

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
  buttonDisabled: boolean = false;
  .
  .
  .
  optionMessages = [
    { id: 1, option: 'Message 1',  message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam bibendum nisi, a malesuada metus consectetur vitae. Proin eget metus eu orci vehicula bibendum ut ut lectus.' },
    { id: 2, option: 'Message 2',  message: 'Quisque et nisl nec mi placerat iaculis. Phasellus dapibus dui tempor, efficitur ligula ut, semper eros. Praesent scelerisque, odio sit amet elementum ornare, ex neque porttitor ipsum, nec sollicitudin mi leo sit amet sapien. Donec porttitor sapien sit amet libero dapibus consequat.' },
    { id: 3, option: 'Message 3',  message: 'Nam accumsan fringilla sapien, ac blandit nunc placerat in. Integer ut est interdum dolor ullamcorper bibendum. Pellentesque dignissim erat vitae eros malesuada lobortis. Praesent pharetra, nunc a hendrerit commodo, diam eros fringilla erat, sit amet porttitor odio erat egestas dolor. Sed pellentesque sed diam a egestas. Integer non rhoncus augue.' },
    { id: 4, option: 'Message 4',  message: 'Donec egestas elit sapien, in dictum mauris euismod ac. Maecenas gravida leo eget quam placerat lobortis. Praesent risus elit, congue sit amet metus egestas, porta aliquam sem. Nam blandit auctor odio non fringilla.' },
    { id: 5, option: 'Message 5',  message: 'Quisque efficitur egestas lectus ut molestie. Mauris eleifend ligula nec dignissim tempus. Aenean nec quam pellentesque, eleifend metus id, efficitur tellus.' },
  ];

  reminderMessageForm = new FormGroup({
    option: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    reminder: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(15) ]),
  });

  get reminder() {
    return this.reminderMessageForm.get('message');
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one Approach: **Reactive form approach**  without ngModel as it stated in warning

```
 export class myComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor( private fb: FormBuilder) {} // add form builder in your comp
      ......
      ...
      reminderMessageForm = this.fb.group({
        option: ['', [Validators.required]],
        reminder: ['', [ Validators.required, [ Validators.minLength(15) ]],
      });

      get reminder() {
        return this.reminderMessageForm.get('message');
      }
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

now in template **reactive form** approach:  remove your ngModel in select box.

While displaying in textArea, display like this :  `value="{{ reminderMessageForm.get('option').value}}"`

```
<form class="reminder-message" [formGroup]="reminderMessageForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="reminderMessage(f.value)">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width select">
        <mat-select formControlName="option" placeholder="Choose a reminder" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of optionMessages" [value]="opt.message">{{ opt.option }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>





    <mat-form-field class="full-width textarea-message">
        <textarea matInput formControlName="reminder" value="{{ reminderMessageForm.get('option').value}}" cols="5" rows="7" readonly></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-dialog-actions class="actions" align="end">
        <button mat-button class="send-message action" [disabled]="!buttonDisabled" type="submit">
            <span>Send</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="close action" (click)="closeDialog()">
            <span>Close</span>
        </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing between Template Driven and Reactive Forms.

Where is selectedReminder in your code ?

```
formControlName="option"
```

is related to

```
option: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
```

Comment: selectedReminder is in <mat-select ... [(ngModel)]="selectedReminder" ..."> and in <textarea ...value="{{ selectedReminder }}" ...></textarea> (that's the connection between both elements).

Thank you for your response but I have the doubt of how replace ngModel in angular 8 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the public documentation of Angular, [**Form Control use with NgModel**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel):

html file

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="first" [(ngModel)]="value">
</form>
```

ts file

```
this.value = 'some value';
```

> This has been deprecated for a few reasons. First, developers have
>   found this pattern confusing. It seems like the actual ngModel
>   directive is being used, but in fact it's an input/output property
>   named ngModel on the reactive form directive that simply approximates
>   (some of) its behavior. Specifically, it allows getting/setting the
>   value and intercepting value events. However, some of ngModel's other
>   features - like delaying updates withngModelOptions or exporting the
>   directive - simply don't work, which has understandably caused some
>   confusion.

To update your code before v7, you'll want to decide whether to stick with reactive form directives (and get/set values using reactive forms patterns) or switch over to template-driven directives.

**Here are the choices:**

**Option 1 - use reactive forms**

html file

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="first">
</form>
```

ts file

```
this.form.get('first').setValue('some value');
```

**Option 2 - use template-driven forms**

html file

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value">
```

ts file

```
this.value = 'some value';
```

By default, when you use this pattern, you will see a deprecation warning once in dev mode. You can choose to silence this warning by providing a config for `ReactiveFormsModule` at import time:

```
imports: [
  ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never'})
]
```

Alternatively, you can choose to surface a separate warning for each instance of this pattern with a config value of "always". This may help to track down where in the code the pattern is being used as the code is being updated.

Other Reference:

- [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27978)

Comment: thank you for your response but I am using a select element. Do you have any idea of how replace ngModel for select elements?>

Comment: @BeatrizIC -- you've probably found this out a while back, but it works  exactly the same way for select elements, using setValue